# CakePHP delete not cascading. Causes foreign key error

Tags: mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys

I have a table called `custom_carts` and I have a table called `custom_cart_items`.

`custom_cart_items` has a foreign key called `custom_cart_id` that is set to `custom_cart.id`

According to the [Cake Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1036/delete), when you call Model->delete() the first param is the id of the entry you want to delete and the second param is whether or not to cascade delete the dependent entries.

So when I call `$this->CustomCart->delete(7,true)` I get this error:

> SQL Error: 1451: Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails
>   (`krake`.`custom_cart_items`,
>   CONSTRAINT `custom_cart_items_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`custom_cart_id`)
>   REFERENCES `custom_carts` (`id`))

Here is the query:

```
DELETE `CustomCart` 
FROM `custom_carts` AS `CustomCart` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` 
ON (`CustomCart`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)  
WHERE `CustomCart`.`id` = 25
```

Shouldn't it *cascade* and dlete the other entry too?

So why am I getting an error?

Comment: what are you associations?  Also - true is the default, so you can remove that.

Comment: also - you're not manually specifying the foreign keys are you?  you shouldn't need to.

Comment: @Dave I am not sure what you are asking. I set up the association by running this query: `ALTER TABLE custom_cart_items ADD FOREIGN KEY (custom_cart_id) REFERENCES custom_cart(id);`

Comment: What is your custom_cart_id field - INT 11?  Can you list out a few of the important fields of each of your tables, and the associations you have for each?  (by editing the question - this will help potential other answerers w/ your question too)

Comment: Could you show the query that CakePHP is executing?

Comment: @Adam I updated my question with the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set the **dependent** parameter to **true** in the model with the **hasmany** relationship in order to enable cascading deletion.

Your model would look something like this:

```
class CustomCart extends AppModel {
         var $name = 'CustomCart';
         var $hasMany = array(
         'CustomCartItem' => array(
             'dependent'=> true
         )
);
}
```

Please see http://book.cakephp.org/view/82/hasMany

Answer (score 0):

Just adding fields to a table (regardless of the field name) does not tell CakePHP that they're associated, nor does it link them for cascading deletion.

You need to set the associations in your model:  [SEE DETAILS HERE](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together).

Comment: Oh ok, I just wasnt sure what you were asking. I do have CustomCart as hasMany CustomCartItem, Do I need to add an association to CustomCartItem as well? belongsTo CustomCart maybe?

Comment: @John - yes, you need to set them both.

Comment: I have associations on both now. CustomCart hasMany CustomCartItem and CustomCartItem belongsTo CustomCart. Still same problem. I also tried using hasOne in place of belongsTo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if you want to delete a record from a table A, and there is another table B which as a FOREIGN KEY constraint on table A, you must set the option on that foreign key of the table B in the Database like this
"SET NULL ON DELETE".

I usually do this in MySqlWorkbench, but you can also use legacy SQL queries to create a table with such an option.